# Partitioning scheme for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ssd, laptop, boot-partition

My laptop has a 240 GB SSD. Right now I'm using Windows. But I'm planning to clean install Ubuntu (Not dual boot). So I need help with the partitioning. Can anyone please suggest me a partition scheme for 240 GB SSD? My laptop has 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Unless you have a specific *use-case*, I'd use the default which is a single partition (and uEFI partition if required for your *unstated* release). Single partition(s) are easier esp. for encrypted installs; though if no encryption is used; I may also separate /home but that's assuming desktop install (you didn't specify) and use a *swap file* (not partition) assuming the *unstated* release defaults to it.  My choice would depend on details you've not provided.  (*simplest is usually best unless you have specific needs*)

Comment: The best partition scheme is the one that works for you. As an opinion, do not over-partiton. Unless you have a particular need for multiple partitions, don't make extra partitions. Ubuntu works perfectly fine installed to a single partition and you don't have to deal with a headache later on because you are running out of space on some partition. Making extra partitions doesn't improve the performance of Ubuntu.  For organization, use folders.

Comment: I'd recommend 25GB for `/`, 8GB for swap, and the rest for `/home`. This will let you upgrade your system without affecting user files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I installed Ubuntu finally some days ago and here is how I partitioned.

1. 50 GB for root
2. 8 GB swap
3. 500 MB for boot
4. 500 MB efi
5. and the rest is for home

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perhaps the file system types will also help!